# Wiring two lights on one switch

Tags: wiring, lighting

I bought some hanging lights to replace two sets of lights in the kitchen. The hanging lights are controlled by two switches on the wall.

There are two holes in the ceiling that each have a bundle of wires hanging through. These were connected to a 3 terminal block but I disconnected them and don't remember how they were connected.

One has: a blue wire with a brown sleeve; a yellow/green wire; a brown wire; and a blue wire. These four wires were in a single terminal block with 2 lots of 3 openings.

The other hole in the ceiling just has brown, blue and yellow wires.

The lights I want to install just have three wires inside their bases.

I was thinking I should connect the lights to the bundles of wires as follows but I'm not certain.

4 wire bundle:
-Blue wire of the light connected to blue wire of ceiling and blue/brown wire of ceiling by putting three wires in the two holes of a terminal block
-brown wire of light connected to brown of ceiling
-yellow of light connected to yellow of ceiling

3 wire bundle:
Match the blue of ceiling to blue of lamp, yellow of ceiling to yellow of lamp and brown of light to brown of light

Is this right? If not please could you explain why with a circuit diagram. Many thanks

Comment: With the power off at the circuit breaker, please take clear, focused pics of the wiring of the switch and each of the ceiling boxes, showing all the wiring. That will make it easiest for the experts here to ensure you get a correct answer. You can [edit] your question and simply drag the pics into the post - they'll automatically get uploaded, hosted & embeded into your post for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  Note that a "cable" is several "wires" wrapped in a sheath. If that's not what you meant, feel free to [edit] your question.